# Animate draggable item to left side of droppable container without overlapping items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm making a URL builder widget that employs jQuery UI draggable/droppable functionality. I can't figure out how to reposition the draggables (after they have been dropped) to the left side of the droppable. Further, I need to make the draggables **not overlap**.

Checkout my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/199gqgk2/) for what I have so far. The draggables snap to the grey area or, otherwise, revert back to their original position.

I thought I might be able to get away with something like this:

```
$("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.draggable).data('hasBeenDropped', true);
        $(ui.draggable).animate({
            left: $(this).position().left
        })
     }
});
```

But that just adds the left position of the container to the `left:0` draggable position. Something about absolute position?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/199gqgk2/1/ is this what you want to achive?

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's close, but the issue I'm having with this method is that because the `div` is detaching from the list and appending to the container, it has no memory of where it came from and the `revert` property doesn't work. This also makes the list of other choices jump. So now I'm trying to provide it with memory and maybe a placeholder.